# referenced assembly reference error

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly

I have 3 Projects. A, B and X

Project X is a class library and holds my EntityFramework EDMX Database Model.
Project X is referenced in Project A.
I want to use Project A and Project X in Project B.

I found out that is a bit more complicated:
I have 4 Projects. A, B, C and X

Project X is a class library and holds my EntityFramework EDMX Database Model.
Project A is a Silverlight Project.
Project B is a SilverlightApplication.Web Project.
Project C is a class library project.

Project X is referenced in Project B.
Project A has Project B as reference. Project B is auto generated in Project A.
Project C should reference Project A, B and X.

Error Message:
"The Type "ProjectX.Location" exists in both "D:\Projectgroup\ProjectA\bin\ProjectA.dll" and "D:\Projectgroup\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.dll"

When I look in the auto generated code of project B in Project A, I see some classes of the DatabaseModel (edmx) of Project X, but not all, which are in the namespace of Project X.

Comment: With your update, it seems your *intentions* are doomed. You should never be in a scenario where you want to reference assemblies from different framework types; a web project and EDMX model are regular .NET assemblies; you shouldn't need to reference a silverlight project and a regular .NET project - that just **won't work**. What is it you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: Agree with @Marc. Consider redesign your solution or provide more details what you want to do and why you should use references as described.

Comment: I only use some resource files of the silverlight project, and that is working well. I stopped now using the silverlight project to avoid the double using of my databasemodel. I know, it would be good to have resources, which are used twice, in a seperate class library.

Answer (score 0):

try using [extern Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) it lets you to wrap assembly inside root-level namespaces named by the alias, which enables them to be used in the same file. though i would recommend you to review the structure of your code so that this could be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the same assembly in the form

```
     /==>A==\
    /        \
    B=======> X
```

is not a problem at all, and should not cause any errors or warnings... *as long as* the `X` is the same identity via both routes. So basically *make sure you only have one version of X*. This is easier if you don't have strong-naming enabled, but even with strong-naming it should just be a case of ensuring your references are correct.

Comment: I have all 3 projects in a project group and have referenced them via add reference -> project group. So, there is only one version of X.

Comment: Error Message: "The Type "ProjectX.Location" exists in both "D:\Projectgroup\ProjectA\bin\ProjectA.dll" and "D:\Projectgroup\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.dll"

Comment: I found out that its a bit more complicated. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem that you have defined two different types with same name in the same namespaces but different assemblies.

For example I got mentioned error in following cases:

**ClassLibrary1.Class1.cs** (Assembly1)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
  public class Class1
  {
  }
}
```

**ClassLibrary2.Class1.cs** (Assembly2)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
  public class Class1
  {
  }
}
```

**Program.cs** (Assembly3)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using ClassLibrary1;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 a;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Therefore, please make sure that you haven't the same name type for different assemblies.

Comment: I found out that its a bit more complicated. Please see my updated post.

Comment: As I understand you have auto generated code. Thus here can be issue, just leave only one type in the same namespace for all projects. Try to clean up auto-generated code and leave only one type definition in project X. This is quite tough to advice something without more details. In any case my suggestion the same you should analyze hierarchy of projects and leave only one type definition.

Comment: I don't know why some classes of my database model get used and some not. I ended up in removing the reference to my silverlight project. Thanks for your hints.